# Python - Final pass of loop with increment value specified

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator

I have the following Python function:

```
def test():

    myval = 277

    for i in range(0, myval, 10):

        print i

test()
```

...when this runs, as the final pass will attempt to iterate 270-279, but come up a few digits short, the loop stops at 270. I understand this is expected behaviour, but before I hack together a workaround, is there a Pythonic way of instructing the iterator to process the last part of the loop, even if it means incrementing by less than the instructed value?

Thanks

Comment: Last past as in only 1 more digit or all 7 remaining digits? You could just use `range(0, myval + 1, 10)`

Comment: hi - it needs to be all remaining 7 digits. thanks.

Comment: So you want, `0 9 19 29 ... 259 269 ...then, 270 271 272 ... 276 277`?

Comment: no...0-9, 10-19...250-259, 260-269, 270-277 is the desired behaviour...

Comment: Isn't that just all numbers from 0-277?

Comment: it's basically setting up the chunking the keys from a dictionary by 10...so return the first ten keys, then the second ten...then whatever remainder is left over...in this case seven keys, return those...right now im just getting the iterator right...

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chunks code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/break-list-chunks-size-n-python/

```
def divide_chunks(max_val, n):
  " Create chunked range of values "
  l = range(max_val + 1)
  # looping till length l 
  for i in range(0, len(l), n):  
    yield l[i:i + n] 

for i, chunk in enumerate(divide_chunks(277, 10)):
  # Chunks of length 10 in range 0 to 277
  print(f'chunk {i} -> {list(chunk)}')
```

**Output**

```
chunk 0 -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chunk 1 -> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
chunk 2 -> [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
chunk 3 -> [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
chunk 4 -> [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
chunk 5 -> [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]
chunk 6 -> [60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69]
chunk 7 -> [70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79]
chunk 8 -> [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89]
chunk 9 -> [90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
chunk 10 -> [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
chunk 11 -> [110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119]
chunk 12 -> [120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129]
chunk 13 -> [130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139]
chunk 14 -> [140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149]
chunk 15 -> [150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159]
chunk 16 -> [160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169]
chunk 17 -> [170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179]
chunk 18 -> [180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189]
chunk 19 -> [190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199]
chunk 20 -> [200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209]
chunk 21 -> [210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219]
chunk 22 -> [220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229]
chunk 23 -> [230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239]
chunk 24 -> [240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249]
chunk 25 -> [250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259]
chunk 26 -> [260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269]
chunk 27 -> [270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def test():
    myval = 277
    for i in range(0, myval, 10):
        print(i)
    lastval = myval % 10
    if(lastval != 0):
        print(myval)

test()
```

If you want the `myval` to be inclusive, change the loop to `for i in range(0, myval + 1, 10):`.